# How do I get rid of the space between these two objects?

Tags: html

```
<body>
<h1><p id="title"><font="Arial">Beyblade Metal Web</font></p></h1>

<br>
<center>
<div id="navbar">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="3.html">Video Games</a></li>
     <li><a href="4.html ">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="5.html ">Tips</a></li>
     <li><a href="6.html ">Episodes</a></li>
     <li><a href="7.html ">Beyblades</a></li>
     <li><a href="8.html ">Products</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</center>
</br>
</body>
```

This is just the body. There's a gap between the "title" and the "navbar" and I want to get rid of it. How can I do that? I would rather not use CSS to fix this problem, but if I have to that's fine.

Comment: Close your header properly with </h1> instead of </1>. Remove the <br>. Consider removing the <br> after the <h1> section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `<p>` and `<h1>` have spacing before and after them. You also have a `<br>` in your code, which is a line break. If you want to remove the spacing, change your `HTML` to this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 style="margin: 0; padding: 0px;"><p id="title" style="margin: 0; padding: 0px;"><font="Arial">Beyblade Metal Web</font></p></h1>
        <div id="navbar" style="text-align: center;">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="3.html">Video Games</a></li>
                <li><a href="4.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="5.html">Tips</a></li>
                <li><a href="6.html">Episodes</a></li>
                <li><a href="7.html">Beyblades</a></li>
                <li><a href="8.html">Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is using `inline CSS` to achieve the results. You may want to put these styles into classes.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<br>` before `<center>`.

Comment: And there is a `</1>` there. Did you mean `</h1>`?

Comment: Oh, now I see it. I will try it.

Comment: That still doesn't fix the space

Answer (score 1):

It indeed is a CSS issue. You should set the `margin` and `padding` properties to `0` on your `h1` and `p` elements like so:

```
h1, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Also, as far as I know, **`p` isn't event allowed to be a child of an `h1` element**, so you might want to drop it anyway...

Comment: `<br>` is a line break. If you noticed, the `<h1>` tag isn't even closed due to a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Take out all the stuff (`<p>`, `<font>`, `<br>`, unclosed `<h1>`) you have adding space between the title and the navbar, so it looks like this:

```
<body>
<h1 style="font-family: arial">Beyblade Metal Web</h1>

<center>
<div id="navbar">

...
```

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OldPro/FRDHz/) for the improvement this makes.  This as about as good as you are going to get without using CSS.